# How can I store datas in application with Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, storage, firebase-storage

I am new in android developing. I try to learn Kotlin. My application is about places. I saved places in a list with recyclerView and also I did authentication and storage in firebase. The last thing I want to do is when I open the application I want to see where I saved in my list. (it means I could not reach the PlaceActivity where I saved datas) But this page is empty. Can you help me? How can I store datas in my application?

Comment: What have you tried to achieve that?

Comment: I tried to achieve datas what I saved before(like image, textview etc).

Comment: I'm sorry but it's still unclear for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have multiple ways to save application data. You need to decide where to store your data.

**Offline Storage:**

1. SharedPreferences [Reference Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences)
2. SQLite Database [Reference Link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm)
3. Room Database [Reference Link](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room)

You can choose another database as well so many libraries are available on GitHub.

**Online Storage:**

1. Firebase [Reference Link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start)

Or you need to implement an API call for saving the data and getting the data.